# ads while debugging mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, adsense

Recently I've stumbled upon a very strange error. I'm creating tutorial asp mvc project (mvc music store, available on many sites). When I debug it with Chrome, ads are showing.

[image]

when I debug it with FF or IE, no ads are shown.

Why is that ? How can I prevent it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange, perhaps you have some sort of adware. Try installing an [ad blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en)